# Android Header Pattern

Tags: android, layout

I am in the process of replacing the Android Popup Menu with a Solid bar containing the buttons at the top of the screen. Now diffident activities contain the same buttons , plus to enhance the user experience we are keeping the Menu Bar with the button. Now i want to make this generic enough. Does anyone know of any good UI Patterns that will help me achieve this. I dont want to copy and paste my layouts xml code, plus the onClick listeners have the same code across the activities. Any help will be appreciated.

Kind Regards,

Mateen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the ActionBar and the [Compatibility Package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html).

Comment: Yes, as it is mentioned there it is compatible back to 1.6.